# What do french mathematicians call a ray?

Tags: terminology, mathematical-french

In the USA we are taught at a young age that a ray is a line with one end, a compromise between a line and a line segment, something like $[0,\infty)$. Is there a word for this in french? I have talked to someone who is french and they did not know what a ray was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"On peut considérer aussi une portion de droite indéﬁnie dans un sens et limitée, dans l’autre, par un point. C’est ce que l’on nomme une demi-droite."  Jacques Hadamard, *Leçons de géométrie élémentaire*, t.1, p.3 (1898).  https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=msu.31293001875347;view=1up;seq=10

Comment: My french is bad, is demidroite the answer?

Comment: Yes, demi-droite is the answer. Sorry.  Droite is a line.

Comment: Literally a 'half-line.'

Comment: A small qualification:  a ray *of light* is referred to as a "rayon" (see a French dictionary under this term).

Comment: I am not having anything to do with light though, I am asking for a mathematical context.